# Drag and Drop - Google Drive

Tags: drag-n-drop

Olá, alguém sabe o que é utilizado ou por onde começar para fazer aquele recurso de arrastar e soltar os arquivos do google drive pra dentro das pastas? Ele junta tudo o que você selecionou, conta e joga na pasta.

Comment: Pode fazer usando Javascript. Mas você tem alguma dúvida em específico? Explicar passo a passo é algo bem amplo por existir vários meios diferentes de fazer esse tipo de recurso. Faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender melhor o modelo do StackOverflow, bem vindo.

Comment: Como você falou de java script, dei uma olhada e achei dois exemplos, mas o do google drive não sei qual é. http://interactjs.io/ e http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/mk/column2/index.html